# Utilizar HashSet y instanceof

Tags: java

¿En el siguiente ejemplo como se podría utilizar el instanceof con un HashSet?.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < empleados.length; i++) {
         if (empleados[i] instanceof Comerciante) {
              numEmpleados++;
          }
  }
```

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que tengas los objetos de tipo `Empleado` en un `HashSet`, entonces solo tienes que recorrerlo con iteradores y aplicar la misma operación sobre cada uno de ellos.

```
HashSet<Empleado> empleados = new HashSet<>();

/* Llenamos la colección con empleados */

// Se recorre la colección
for (Empleado e : empleados) {
    if (e instanceof Comerciante)
        /* Acción */;
}
```

Este iterador, llamado `forEach`, te hace el recorrido automáticamente.
Definimos una variable `e` que hará referencia en cada paso a un elemento (en este caso empleado) de la colección.

También puedes hacerlo de manera manual, obteniendo un iterador con el método `iterator()` de `Collection` y manejandolo explícitamente.

```
Iterator<Empleado> it = empleados.iterator();
Empleado e;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    e = it.next();
    if (e instanceof Comerciante)
        /* Acción */;
}
```

En esta segunda forma, accedemos al elemento de la colección mediante el método `next` del iterador, comprobando antes que haya un siguiente elemento que no se haya procesado aún.